# Woocommerce add product gallery images not working

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

When I click "Add product gallery images" from a WooCommerce product the modal of adding new pictures does not appear. When I check the console I receive the following error every time I click the "Add product gallery images" link.

```
meta-boxes-product.min.js:1 Uncaught TypeError: wp.media.controller.Library is not a constructor
at HTMLAnchorElement.<anonymous> (meta-boxes-product.min.js:1)
at HTMLParagraphElement.dispatch (load-scripts.php?c=1&load[chunk_0]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils,jquery-ui-core,jquery-ui-widget,jquery-ui-mouse,jquery-ui-sortable,underscore,backbone,wp-util,&load[chunk_1]=wp-backbone,media-models,moxiejs,plupload&ver=5.4.4:3)
at HTMLParagraphElement.r.handle (load-scripts.php?c=1&load[chunk_0]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils,jquery-ui-core,jquery-ui-widget,jquery-ui-mouse,jquery-ui-sortable,underscore,backbone,wp-util,&load[chunk_1]=wp-backbone,media-models,moxiejs,plupload&ver=5.4.4:3)
```

I have read that perhaps a plugin makes a conflict but even when I disabled one by one, the problem remains. When switched to a default wordpress theme (as ozgur suggested in comments), the link is working.

Any ideas how to investigate more in this ?

Thank you

Comment: Your theme or one of your plugins might be causing javascript conflicts. You can try to select one of the default Wordpress themes and see if you can use Product Gallery Images there.

Comment: Can you make sure your theme is up-to-date? Probably it isn't compatible with the Woocommerce version that you are using

Comment: @ozgur i 'll contact the theme creator. thanks